# how can I check the mount count on a ext2 filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext2

With `tune2fs` one can set the maximum mount count `-c` (before e2fsck kicks in on boot) and also the actual (current) mount count `-C`. I'm looking for a way to *read* these two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the man page has `-l`:

```
sehe@desktop:~$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/debian-uburoot  | grep count
Inode count:              1310720
Block count:              5241856
Reserved block count:     262092
Mount count:              12
Maximum mount count:      -1
```

So you could make it

```
function mount_count() 
{ 
    tune2fs -l "$1" | 
      grep '^Mount count:' | 
      grep -oP '\d+'
}
```

Now you can

```
mounted=$(mount_count /dev/sda1)
echo "Volume sda1 has already been mounted $mounted times since last check"
```

Comment: I also found `dumpe2fs`